# Postgres Amend Current date from mmyyyy to mm-yyyy

Tags: postgresql

I have a table within postgres which has a month year column formatted as mmyyyy, how do I go about either adding a new column, or amending the exisiting column so I can have the format as mm-yyyy please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert it to a proper date (at the start of the month), then format that date back the way you want it:

```
to_char(to_date(the_column, 'mmyyyy'), 'mm-yyyy')
```

You can use that in a SELECT query, create view or UPDATE the column using that expression.

Alternatively use a simple string manipulation:

```
left(the_column, 2)||'-'||right(the_column, 4)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried this, but now getting an error message. 

The column name is mmyyyy and is a character(6)

UPDATE public.dim_calendar
 SET  mmyyyy = left(mmyyyy, 2)||'-'||right(mmyyyy, 4)

This is the error message:
ERROR:  value too long for type character(6)
SQL state: 22001

Comment: Well, "*value too long for type character(6)*"  is obvious isn't it? You need to increase the allowed length of the column (and [stop using char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29))

Comment: This is new to me so wasn;t sure if I needed to amend something within the UPDATE code. That has worked perfectly, thank yyou